# select one column less/greater than specific number

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want the result of this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= '1460316600'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '1460316600'
```

// Result=> Some rows...

but not with UNION however with:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '1460316600' AND date <= '1460316600'
```

// Result=> Has no result :(

How can I do that?

Comment: Switch AND to OR to get more or less same result. (UNION removes duplicates, SELECT without DISTINCT doesn't.)

Comment: If you use <= and => you mean select for all value .. are you sure for you want < and > (not equal) instead?

Comment: update question with sample data and desired output

Comment: @jarlh I had changed it but it didn't work!

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE date >= '1460316600' OR date <= '1460316600'` like @jarlh has recommend you

Comment: @scaisEdge yes I'm sure, because I want period of time not only ONE!

Comment: @dnoeth I will check it and say!

Comment: @AliFarjam the 2 date's in your query, are they the same column in your table?

Comment: @Alexej Sommer Thanks so much dear Alexej Sommer, it worked :D

Comment: But the first `1460316600` and the second `1460316600` are equal. If you check if they are more or equal, OR less or equal, then it would always be true right? (A date is always more, less or equal to another date)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like answer is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '1460316600' OR date < '1460316600'
```

like @jarlh has recommend in comments

It would be equal to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= '1460316600'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '1460316600'
```

Comment: DISTINCT * is nonsensical, as is <=>